# Can I create a Custom CreatePage.aspx (Enterprise Wiki)?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio-2013

Is is possible to make a custom CreatePage.aspx? What I would like to do is add the EditForm page to the CreatePage so it can pull fields from the custom page layout. With the fields pulled from the custom layout I could then fill out all the information in the CreatePage without having to make a page, name it, and then go to the page and edited it after creation.

Answer (score 0):

Even with documents in SharePoint you upload/create first, then edit properties. The reason being there is nothing to edit (attach data to) until it's created in the database. It would be possible to hack something up to store the data until after creation, then go in and edit. Perhaps jquery or something with a delay before writing.